# Expanding TikZ automata from a single line to a grid

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm doing my thesis on Queueing Theory and I have a really hard time working with TikZ library in LaTeX. I managed to get the first line, but somehow I am not able to go down. Could anyone please be so kind and help me out coding the following image into LaTeX please?

[image]

So far I've gotten to:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning}


\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[state]             (0) {0};
        \node[state, right=of 0] (1) {1};
        \node[state, right=of 1] (2) {2};
        \node[state, right=of 2] (3) {3};
        \node[draw=none,  right=of 3]   (4) {$\cdots$};

        \draw[every loop]
            (0) edge[bend right, auto=right] node {$\lambda$} (1)
            (1) edge[bend right, auto=right] node {$\mu$} (0)
            (1) edge[bend right, auto=right] node {$\lambda$} (2)
            (2) edge[bend right, auto=right] node {$\mu$} (1)
            (2) edge[bend right, auto=right] node {$\lambda$} (3)
            (3) edge[bend right, auto=right] node {$\mu$} (2)
            (3) edge[bend right, auto=right] node {$\lambda$} (4)
            (4) edge[bend right, auto=right] node {$\mu$} (3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{De M/M/1-wachtrij.}
\end{figure}
```

But that is just a one line version. How can i go down and thus add multiple rows? I am very new to LaTeX, so any help or tips will be extremely welcome!

This is what the second row from the picture looks like:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you consider using `pstricks` for this picture?

Comment: That is not hard. Take a look at matrices in tikz or the foreach statement

Comment: Minimal working examples are usually welcome, as for a starting-point to help you. If you already have the first row, you could add that code. Also it seems this could be done by some loops.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It takes a while to compile. but here I TABstack various `tikz` components.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,tabstackengine,amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning}
\stackMath
\setstackgap{S}{-4pt}
\newcommand\rlarrow[2]{\smash{\vcenter{\hbox{\kern-5pt%
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \node             (0) {};
        \node[right=of 0] (1) {};
        \draw[every loop]
            (0) edge[bend left, auto=left] node {$#1$} (1)
            (1) edge[bend left, auto=left] node {$#2$} (0);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\kern-5pt}}}}
\newcommand\rarrow[1]{\kern-5pt\smash{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \node             (0) {};
        \node[right=of 0] (1) {};
        \draw[every loop]
            (0) edge[bend left, auto=left] node {$#1$} (1);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}\kern-5pt}
\newcommand\uarrow[1]{\makebox[0pt]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \node             (0) {};
        \node[below=of 0] (1) {};
        \draw[every loop]
            (1) edge[bend left, auto=left] node {\makebox[0pt][r]{$#1$}} (0);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\kern5pt}}
\newcommand\darrow[1]{\makebox[0pt]{\kern5pt%
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \node             (0) {};
        \node[below=of 0] (1) {};
        \draw[every loop]
            (0) edge[bend left, auto=left] node {\makebox[0pt][l]{$#1$}} (1);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}}
\begin{document}
\tabbedShortstack{
\fbox{0}&\rarrow{\lambda}&\fbox{1}&\rarrow{\lambda}&\fbox{2}&\rarrow{\lambda}&
  \fbox{3}&\rarrow{\lambda}&\fbox{4}&\rarrow{\lambda}&\fbox{5}&\,\cdots\\
\uarrow{\sigma}&&\darrow{\theta}&&\darrow{2\theta}&&\darrow{3\theta}&&\darrow{4\theta}&&
  \darrow{5\theta}&\\
\fbox{0}&\rlarrow{\lambda}{\mu}&\fbox{1}&\rlarrow{\lambda}{\mu}&\fbox{2}&
  \rlarrow{\lambda}{\mu}&\fbox{3}&\rlarrow{\lambda}{\mu}&\fbox{4}&
  \rlarrow{\lambda}{\mu}&\fbox{5}&\,\cdots\\
\uarrow{2\sigma}&&\uarrow{\sigma}&&\darrow{\theta}&&\darrow{2\theta}&&
  \darrow{3\theta}&&\darrow{4\theta}&\\
\fbox{0}&\rlarrow{\lambda}{\mu}&\fbox{1}&\rlarrow{\lambda}{2\mu}&\fbox{2}&
  \rlarrow{\lambda}{2\mu}&\fbox{3}&\rlarrow{\lambda}{2\mu}&\fbox{4}&
  \rlarrow{\lambda}{2\mu}&\fbox{5}&\,\cdots\\
\uarrow{3\sigma}&&\uarrow{2\sigma}&&\uarrow{\sigma}&&\darrow{\theta}&&
  \darrow{2\theta}&&\darrow{3\theta}&\\
\fbox{0}&\rlarrow{\lambda}{\mu}&\fbox{1}&\rlarrow{\lambda}{2\mu}&\fbox{2}&
  \rlarrow{\lambda}{3\mu}&\fbox{3}&\rlarrow{\lambda}{3\mu}&\fbox{4}&
  \rlarrow{\lambda}{3\mu}&\fbox{5}&\,\cdots\\
\uarrow{4\sigma}&&\uarrow{3\sigma}&&\uarrow{2\sigma}&&\uarrow{\sigma}&&\darrow{\theta}&&
  \darrow{2\theta}&\\
\fbox{0}&\rlarrow{\lambda}{\mu}&\fbox{1}&\rlarrow{\lambda}{2\mu}&\fbox{2}&
  \rlarrow{\lambda}{3\mu}&\fbox{3}&\rlarrow{\lambda}{4\mu}&\fbox{4}&
  \rlarrow{\lambda}{4\mu}&\fbox{5}&\,\cdots\\
  \vdots&&\vdots&&\vdots&&\vdots&&\vdots&&\vdots&
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I can get it to compile in about half the time, if I change the TABstack to a very customized `array`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath,array}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning}
\newcommand\rlarrow[2]{\smash{\vcenter{\hbox{\kern-5pt%
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \node             (0) {};
        \node[right=of 0] (1) {};
        \draw[every loop]
            (0) edge[bend left, auto=left] node {$#1$} (1)
            (1) edge[bend left, auto=left] node {$#2$} (0);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\kern-5pt}}}}
\newcommand\rarrow[1]{\kern-5pt\smash{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \node             (0) {};
        \node[right=of 0] (1) {};
        \draw[every loop]
            (0) edge[bend left, auto=left] node {$#1$} (1);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}\kern-5pt}
\newcommand\uarrow[1]{\makebox[0pt]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \node             (0) {};
        \node[below=of 0] (1) {};
        \draw[every loop]
            (1) edge[bend left, auto=left] node {\makebox[0pt][r]{$#1$}} (0);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\kern5pt}}
\newcommand\darrow[1]{\makebox[0pt]{\kern5pt%
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \node             (0) {};
        \node[below=of 0] (1) {};
        \draw[every loop]
            (0) edge[bend left, auto=left] node {\makebox[0pt][l]{$#1$}} (1);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}}
\begin{document}
\arraycolsep=0pt
\renewcommand\arraystretch{0}
$\begin{array}{cccccccccccc}
\fbox{0}&\rarrow{\lambda}&\fbox{1}&\rarrow{\lambda}&\fbox{2}&\rarrow{\lambda}&
  \fbox{3}&\rarrow{\lambda}&\fbox{4}&\rarrow{\lambda}&\fbox{5}&\,\cdots\\[-5pt]
\uarrow{\sigma}&&\darrow{\theta}&&\darrow{2\theta}&&\darrow{3\theta}&&\darrow{4\theta}&&
  \darrow{5\theta}&\\[-5pt]
\fbox{0}&\rlarrow{\lambda}{\mu}&\fbox{1}&\rlarrow{\lambda}{\mu}&\fbox{2}&
  \rlarrow{\lambda}{\mu}&\fbox{3}&\rlarrow{\lambda}{\mu}&\fbox{4}&
  \rlarrow{\lambda}{\mu}&\fbox{5}&\,\cdots\\[-5pt]
\uarrow{2\sigma}&&\uarrow{\sigma}&&\darrow{\theta}&&\darrow{2\theta}&&
  \darrow{3\theta}&&\darrow{4\theta}&\\[-5pt]
\fbox{0}&\rlarrow{\lambda}{\mu}&\fbox{1}&\rlarrow{\lambda}{2\mu}&\fbox{2}&
  \rlarrow{\lambda}{2\mu}&\fbox{3}&\rlarrow{\lambda}{2\mu}&\fbox{4}&
  \rlarrow{\lambda}{2\mu}&\fbox{5}&\,\cdots\\[-5pt]
\uarrow{3\sigma}&&\uarrow{2\sigma}&&\uarrow{\sigma}&&\darrow{\theta}&&
  \darrow{2\theta}&&\darrow{3\theta}&\\[-5pt]
\fbox{0}&\rlarrow{\lambda}{\mu}&\fbox{1}&\rlarrow{\lambda}{2\mu}&\fbox{2}&
  \rlarrow{\lambda}{3\mu}&\fbox{3}&\rlarrow{\lambda}{3\mu}&\fbox{4}&
  \rlarrow{\lambda}{3\mu}&\fbox{5}&\,\cdots\\[-5pt]
\uarrow{4\sigma}&&\uarrow{3\sigma}&&\uarrow{2\sigma}&&\uarrow{\sigma}&&\darrow{\theta}&&
  \darrow{2\theta}&\\[-5pt]
\fbox{0}&\rlarrow{\lambda}{\mu}&\fbox{1}&\rlarrow{\lambda}{2\mu}&\fbox{2}&
  \rlarrow{\lambda}{3\mu}&\fbox{3}&\rlarrow{\lambda}{4\mu}&\fbox{4}&
  \rlarrow{\lambda}{4\mu}&\fbox{5}&\,\cdots\\[-2pt]
  \vdots&&\vdots&&\vdots&&\vdots&&\vdots&&\vdots&
\end{array}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Whoa! This looks magnificent. I copied your code into a new tex-file, but I'm getting the following error:

Use of \\tabbedShortstack doesn't match its definition.
<argument> \def \reserved@a {
                             \def \@currenvir {tikzpicture}\edef \@currenvli...
l.64 }

Comment: @RobinGregoor Perhaps your `tabstackengine` is out of date.  `Ver­sion  2.01 2016-11-30` on http://ctan.org/pkg/tabstackengine.  I also edited my answer to give an `array` alternative to `tabstackengine`.

Comment: You were right. I'm using Overleaf for compiling my LaTeX, so that might be outdated indeed. The array version works just fine in there!
Now the only thing I want to change are the entries inside the boxes, since it's in 2 dimensions. In your code I can't find the spot to change that. Like, the first row has to go from 0,0 to 0,5 and the last row from 5,0 to 5,5.

Comment: @RobinGregoor All the boxed numbers are created via `\fbox{}`.  So just look for the `\fbox` entries and change the numbers therein.

Comment: Perfect! Got it all sorted out now, thank you! Since it's not a picture, can I still add a caption to this?

Comment: @RobinGregoor Sure, just wrap `\begin{figure}
\centering...\caption{My diagram}
\end{figure}` around the `array` stuff.

Comment: I'm sorry but this may sound extremely stupid... but I can't get it to work. The caption is above the picture instead of below and the whole matrix array picture is moved above my section title. I can't post my code or a picture in the comments, right?

Comment: @RobinGregoor A `figure` is a `float`, which means that LaTeX picks the place where to best place it, though sometimes it is not where you want.  You can guide `figure` with its optional argument, `\begin{figure}[ht]...` to tell it to try to place it "`h`ere" first, and only then at the `t`op of the page.  Other options are `b`ottom and `p`age-by-itself.  As to the `\caption` location, placing `\caption` either before or after the `array` should make the actual caption appear either before or after the array.

Comment: @RobinGregoor  If all else fails, the `caption` package offers the `\captionof{figure}{my caption}` macro, to be used without a `\begin{figure}...\end{figure` environment, to keep the image from `float`ing around the page.

Comment: Adding [h] and \caption to the end worked like a charm. Thanks a lot! You saved my life!

Answer (score 12):

You can start with following code, you jsut need a `matrix` and some `foreach` loops to draw this kind of schemes.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}

\begin{document}

        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzset{
            state/.style = {draw, minimum size=1cm, anchor=center},
            array/.style = {matrix of nodes, nodes=state, row sep=1cm, column sep=1cm},
        }
        \matrix[array] (A) {
            0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
            0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
            0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
            0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
            0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
        };
        \foreach \j in {1,...,5}{
                \node[right= 2mm of A-\j-6] {\dots};
                \foreach \i [remember=\i as \lasti (initially 1)] in {2,...,6}{
                    \draw (A-\j-\lasti) edge[bend left] node[above] {$\lambda$} (A-\j-\i);}
            } 

        \foreach \i in {1,...,6}
                \node[below= 2mm of A-5-\i] {\vdots};

        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Update:

I've managed to find a relation to define edge labels with `foreach` loops for lambda, sigma and theta. But mu labels have been applied in manually defined loops. Now your homework will be to understand them.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}

\begin{document}

        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzset{
            state/.style = {draw, minimum size=1cm, anchor=center},
            array/.style = {matrix of nodes, nodes=state, row sep=1cm, column sep=1cm},
        }
        \matrix[array] (A) {
            0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
            0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
            0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
            0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
            0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
        };
          % end row dots and \lambdas
        \foreach \j in {1,...,5}{
                \node[right= 2mm of A-\j-6] {\dots};
                \foreach \i [remember=\i as \lasti (initially 1)] in {2,...,6}{
                    \draw[->] (A-\j-\lasti) edge[bend left] node[above] {$\lambda$} (A-\j-\i);}
            } 

        %Sigma
        \foreach \i [count= \ni] in {2,...,5}{
            \foreach \j [remember=\j as \lastj (initially \ni), count=\nj, evaluate=\nj as \text using {ifthenelse(\nj==1,,\nj)} ] in {\i,...,5}
                \draw[<-] (A-\lastj-\ni) edge[bend right] node[left] {$\text\sigma$} (A-\j-\ni);            
        }

        %Theta
        \foreach \i [count= \ni, remember=\i as \lasti (initially 1)] in {2,...,5}{
            \foreach \j [count=\nj, evaluate=\nj as \text using {ifthenelse(\nj==1,,\nj)} ] in {\i,...,6}
                \draw[->] (A-\lasti-\j) edge[bend left] node[right] {$\text\theta$} (A-\i-\j);          
        }

       %mus second row
        \foreach \i [remember=\i as \lasti (initially 1)] in {2,...,6}{
            \draw[<-] (A-2-\lasti) edge[bend right] node[below] {$\mu$} (A-2-\i);}

       %third row mus
        \foreach \i [count=\ni, evaluate=\ni as \nexti using {int(\ni+1)}] in {$\mu$,$2\mu$,$2\mu$,$2\mu$,$2\mu$}{
            \draw[->] (A-3-\nexti) edge[bend left] node[below] {\i} (A-3-\ni);}

       %fourth row mus
        \foreach \i [count=\ni, evaluate=\ni as \nexti using {int(\ni+1)}] in {$\mu$,$2\mu$,$3\mu$,$3\mu$,$3\mu$}{
            \draw[->] (A-4-\nexti) edge[bend left] node[below] {\i} (A-4-\ni);}

       %fifth row mus
        \foreach \i [count=\ni, evaluate=\ni as \nexti using {int(\ni+1)}] in {$\mu$,$2\mu$,$3\mu$,$4\mu$,$4\mu$}{
            \draw[->] (A-5-\nexti) edge[bend left] node[below] {\i} (A-5-\ni);}

        \foreach \i in {1,...,6}
                \node[below= 2mm of A-5-\i] {\vdots};

        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow that looks so much easier than my big pile of code!
How can i change the lines to arrows?

Comment: And another question: Does the foreach loop also work for different labels on the arrows. As you can see in the picture, it goes from 1*mu to 2*mu, etcetera

Comment: @RobinGregoor: Yes, if you know the relation between them. See updated answer.

Answer (score 7):

A `\foreach`-only solution.

I think to have found a rule also for the `\mu`s.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{%
    state/.style={draw, rectangle, minimum height=2em, minimum width=2em},
    >=stealth
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % nodes, dots and lamba arrows
        \foreach \linenum in {1,2,...,5}{%
            \foreach \nodenum in {0,1,...,5}{%
                \node[state] at (2.5*\nodenum,2-2.5*\linenum) (N-\linenum-\nodenum) {\nodenum};
            }
            \foreach \nodenum [evaluate=\nodenum as \nextnode using int(\nodenum+1)] in {0,1,...,4}{% 
                \draw[->] (N-\linenum-\nodenum) edge[bend left, auto=left] node {$\lambda$} (N-\linenum-\nextnode);
            }
            \node[right=1em of N-\linenum-5] {\Huge \dots}; 
        }
        \foreach \nodenum in {0,1,...,5}{%
            \node[below=-1ex of N-5-\nodenum, scale=2] {$\vdots$}; 
        }
        % mu arrows
        \foreach \linenum [evaluate=\linenum as \k using {ifthenelse(\linenum==2,,int(\linenum-1))},
                           evaluate=\linenum as \startnode using int(\linenum-2)] in {2,3,4,5} {%  
            \foreach \nodenum [evaluate=\nodenum as \nextnode using int(\nodenum+1)] in {\startnode,...,4} {%
                \draw[<-] (N-\linenum-\nodenum) edge[bend right, auto=right] node {$\mathstrut\k\mu$} (N-\linenum-\nextnode);
            }
        }
        \foreach \linenum [evaluate=\linenum as \endnode using int(\linenum-3)] in {4,5} {%  
            \foreach \nodenum [evaluate=\nodenum as \nextnode using int(\nodenum+1),
                               evaluate=\nodenum as \k using {ifthenelse(\nodenum==0,,int(\nodenum+1))}] in {0,...,\endnode} {%
                \draw[<-] (N-\linenum-\nodenum) edge[bend right, auto=right] node {$\mathstrut\k\mu$} (N-\linenum-\nextnode);
            }
        }
        % sigma arrows
        \foreach \linenum [evaluate=\linenum as \i using int(\linenum+1),
                           evaluate=\linenum as \endnode using int(\linenum-1)] in {1,2,3,4} {%
            \foreach \nodenum [evaluate=\nodenum as \k using {ifthenelse(int(\linenum-\nodenum)==1,,int(\linenum-\nodenum))}] in {0,...,\endnode}{%
                \draw[->] (N-\i-\nodenum) edge[bend left, auto=left] node {$\mathstrut\k\sigma$} (N-\linenum-\nodenum);
            }
        }
        % theta arrows
        \foreach \linenum [evaluate=\linenum as \nextline using int(\linenum+1)] in {1,2,...,4} {%
            \foreach \nodenum [evaluate=\nodenum as \k using {ifthenelse(int(\linenum)==int(\nodenum),,int(\nodenum-\linenum+1))}] in {\linenum,...,5} {%
                \draw[->] (N-\linenum-\nodenum) edge[bend left, auto=left] node {$\mathstrut\k\theta$} (N-\nextline-\nodenum);
            }               
        }   
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\caption{De M/M/1-wachtrij.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! This got me started very well. Only thing I'm worried about is the mu, sigma and theta parts, since they differ between each set of nodes or they are not always present. Is this also fixable with a foreach loop, or should I just mention every single one individually?

Comment: @RobinGregoor Of course you can do it with a foreach loop, I'll show you asap!

Comment: @RobinGregoor I've already many excellent answers but I've completed mine as well, I think to have found a rule for `\mu` arrows, too.

Answer (score 6):

With `tikz-cd`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\newcommand{\rgarr}[2]{\arrow[#1,bend left,shift right=1ex,"#2"]}
\newcommand{\rgbox}[1]{\fbox{$#1$}}
\newcommand{\rgdot}[1]{\arrow[#1,dotted,no head]}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=large,row sep=large]
  \rgbox{0} \rgarr{r}{\lambda}
& \rgbox{1} \rgarr{r}{\lambda} \rgarr{d}{\theta}
& \rgbox{2} \rgarr{r}{\lambda} \rgarr{d}{2\theta}
& \rgbox{3} \rgarr{r}{\lambda} \rgarr{d}{3\theta}
& \rgbox{4} \rgarr{r}{\lambda} \rgarr{d}{4\theta}
& \rgbox{5}                    \rgarr{d}{5\theta} \rgdot{r} &[-3em] {}
\\
\rgbox{0} \rgarr{r}{\lambda}                   \rgarr{u}{\sigma}
& \rgbox{1} \rgarr{r}{\lambda} \rgarr{l}{\mu}  \rgarr{d}{\theta}
& \rgbox{2} \rgarr{r}{\lambda} \rgarr{l}{\mu}  \rgarr{d}{2\theta}
& \rgbox{3} \rgarr{r}{\lambda} \rgarr{l}{\mu}  \rgarr{d}{3\theta}
& \rgbox{4} \rgarr{r}{\lambda} \rgarr{l}{\mu}  \rgarr{d}{4\theta}
& \rgbox{5}                    \rgarr{l}{\mu}  \rgarr{d}{5\theta} \rgdot{r} & {}
\\
  \rgbox{0} \rgarr{r}{\lambda}                 \rgarr{u}{2\sigma}
& \rgbox{1} \rgarr{r}{\lambda} \rgarr{l}{\mu}  \rgarr{u}{\sigma}
& \rgbox{2} \rgarr{r}{\lambda} \rgarr{l}{2\mu} \rgarr{d}{\theta}
& \rgbox{3} \rgarr{r}{\lambda} \rgarr{l}{2\mu} \rgarr{d}{2\theta}
& \rgbox{4} \rgarr{r}{\lambda} \rgarr{l}{2\mu} \rgarr{d}{3\theta}
& \rgbox{5}                    \rgarr{l}{2\mu} \rgarr{d}{4\theta} \rgdot{r} & {}
\\
  \rgbox{0} \rgarr{r}{\lambda}                 \rgarr{u}{3\sigma}
& \rgbox{1} \rgarr{r}{\lambda} \rgarr{l}{\mu}  \rgarr{u}{2\sigma}
& \rgbox{2} \rgarr{r}{\lambda} \rgarr{l}{2\mu} \rgarr{u}{\sigma}
& \rgbox{3} \rgarr{r}{\lambda} \rgarr{l}{3\mu} \rgarr{d}{\theta}
& \rgbox{4} \rgarr{r}{\lambda} \rgarr{l}{3\mu} \rgarr{d}{2\theta}
& \rgbox{5}                    \rgarr{l}{3\mu} \rgarr{d}{3\theta} \rgdot{r} & {}
\\
  \rgbox{0} \rgarr{r}{\lambda}                 \rgarr{u}{4\sigma} \rgdot{d}
& \rgbox{1} \rgarr{r}{\lambda} \rgarr{l}{\mu}  \rgarr{u}{3\sigma} \rgdot{d}
& \rgbox{2} \rgarr{r}{\lambda} \rgarr{l}{2\mu} \rgarr{u}{2\sigma} \rgdot{d}
& \rgbox{3} \rgarr{r}{\lambda} \rgarr{l}{3\mu} \rgarr{u}{\sigma}  \rgdot{d}
& \rgbox{4} \rgarr{r}{\lambda} \rgarr{l}{4\mu}                    \rgdot{d}
& \rgbox{5}                    \rgarr{l}{4\mu} \rgdot{r} \rgdot{d} & {}
\\[-2em]
{} & {} & {} & {} & {} & {}
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]